# ROW_NUMBER() OVER() MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Mirando la documentación de MySql sobre `row_number() over()` veo que se puede hacer, estoy copiando exactamente el mismo ejemplo adaptándolo a la BBDD en la que trabajo pero da el siguiente error

> `"(" is not valid at this position, expecting: EOF, ';'`

Dejo la select para que la veais. Gracias de antemano.

```
select e.esap_codigo, e.esap_iden,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by e.esap_codigo order by e.esap_codigo, e.esap_iden) as num    
from esap_hco_estados_aparatos e;
```

Comment: Que versión usas de mysql?

Comment: Es la 8.0.12, por lo que he leído vale a partir de la 8.0.0. De momento he solucionado con esto que acabo de probar.

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de probar esto y funciona, igualmente me gustaría saber si es posible el tema del over,

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @db_names:='';
SELECT @row_number:=CASE 
    WHEN @db_names=esap_codigo THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,@db_names:=esap_codigo AS num,
    e.esap_codigo,e.esap_estado, e.esap_fecha, e.esap_destinatario, e.esap_tipo_destino, e.esap_proveedor, e.esap_user_alta 
FROM esap_hco_estados_aparatos e where year(esap_fecha)=2018;
```